# How to set maximum string length in NSTextField in swift?

Tags: swift3

I like to set the max length of text displayed in a NSTextField so that the long text should be truncated and ended with two dots (..).

The problem is that different languages have different lengths even they have same number of characters.
E.g.
 let myTitle1 =  "Lake"   // 4 English characters
     let myTitle2 =  "我的标题" // 4 Chinese characters
     let myTitle3 =  "A beautiful Lake" // 16 English characters

I like above three titles display with similar (if not exactly same) length in NSTestField like this:
"Lake"
"我的.."
"A be.."

Are there any ways to do it?

thanks

Comment: But the control is used for entry so what would you do with the rest of the characters as the user enters them?

Comment: I use it as a title in customized tabview.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late but for anyone else looking for an answere. You should not manually truncate text, let the OS do it for you.

Align the textfield in your storyboard as you want it and set the line break to truncate tail.

[image]

Also set the textfields compression resistance to a low value else the textfield borders will get pushed instead of the text being trucated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    //MARK:-  Login 
    @IBAction func performLogin(_ sender: Any){
    //Username & Password - CHARACTER LIMIT CHECK
    guard isLoginFormCharLimitValid else {
        return
    }
    
      //Need to call API
      print("Redy To Call API")
   }

    //MARK:-  Username & Password - CHARACTER LIMIT CHECK 
    private var isLoginFormCharLimitValid: Bool {
    var isLoginFormCharLimitValid: Bool = true
    
    //Username Field Characters Length
    let userNameLength = (usernameTextField.stringValue as NSString).length
    if userNameLength > AppConstant.IntValues.twofiftyfive.rawValue {
        //Need to show Error Message Here
        errorLabel.stringValue = LoginValidationMessages.userNameFieldCharacterLimit.localized
        isLoginFormCharLimitValid = false
        return isLoginFormCharLimitValid
    }
    
    //Password Field Characters Length
    let passwordLength = (passwordTextField.stringValue as NSString).length
    if passwordLength > AppConstant.IntValues.twofiftyfive.rawValue {
        //Need to show Error Message Here
        errorLabel.stringValue = LoginValidationMessages.passwordFieldCharacterLimit.localized
        isLoginFormCharLimitValid = false
        return isLoginFormCharLimitValid
    }
    
    errorLabel.stringValue = EMPTY_STRING
    return isLoginFormCharLimitValid
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
     if(textField == myTitle1){
        return newLength <= 4
     }else if(textField == myTitle2){
       return newLength <= 4
     }else{
       return newLength <= 16
   }
    return true // Bool
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the length of the texts are variable. and how to call this function in my code?

Comment: if you working with textField, then above code is working

Comment: OP asked about NSTextField (MacOS), you are replying about iOS UITextField.